# read and process file using multithread

Tags: c#, multithreading, for-loop

I'm reading one folder containing about 200 files. I think it is to create 4 stream to read the file at 4 to 1 1 loop. But I can not pass an array error control.
this is Example:

```
FileInfo[] fileArray = _directoryInfo.GetFiles("*.txt");
for(int i = 0; i<fileArray.Length;i+=4)
{
    Thread t1 = new Thread(function(fileArray[i]));
    t1.Start();
    Thread t2 = new Thread(function(fileArray[i+1]));
    t2.Start();
    Thread t3 = new Thread(function(fileArray[i+2]));
    t3.Start();
    Thread t4 = new Thread(function(fileArray[i+3]));
    t4.Start();
}
```

but result was received on

```
IndexOutOfRangeException
```

I check fileArray have 200 file txt.
I need a solution...

Comment: Unless you wait for those 4 threads at the end of each loop, you'll have more than 4 threads started...

Comment: Is that your _actual_ code? That are the `new Thread(function(fileArray[1+2]))` lines are _exactly_ that? Or is it actually a lambda function more like: `new Thread(() => function(fileArray[1+2]))`? If the latter, this may be party due to a closure issue where _all/most_ of your threads are executing using the last value for `i` (being 200+, so looking up `fileArray[200], fileArray[201], fileArray[202], fileArray[203]`)

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i<fileArray.Length;i+=4)//Here is the problem
```

You check for `i<fileArray.Length` but you access `fileArray[i+3]` inside the loop.

Am unsure why are you starting `4` threads at a time. You can simply write the above code like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i<fileArray.Length;i++)
{
    Thread t1 = new Thread(function(fileArray[i]));
    t1.Start();
}
```

Also note that starting large number of threads is never a good idea, keep in mind your machine is capable of executing only `N` number of threads at the same time, where `N` is number of cores.

Comment: I think of the array is _exactly_ 200 items (or any divisible by 4 number) it will work. But I agree, in general this is an issue. Maybe not _the_ issue, but definitely one of them. (I think the other might be a lambda closure issue)